# Are these external HDD clicking noises a sign of failure

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Hello I've got this external HDD for about a year, and now sometimes, usually overnight, I hear clicking noises coming from it. It keeps going maybe for less than 3 minutes and randomly starts again for about the same amount of time and repeats. Sometimes you don't hear it click at all throughout the day. The HDD seems to be working fine, it almost has 6 months left on it's warranty, do I need to be worried or back up the content? Do I have to put it under stress so it dies faster?

Are these clicking noises normal?

This is my model, a 2TB WD Elements: [https://www.amazon.com/Western-Digital-Elements-Portable-External/dp/B06W55K9N6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06W55K9N6)

Here I recoded an audio: http://sndup.net/sxsj

And here I recorded a video: https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/845652406

`wmic diskdrive get status` returns status OK for all my devices!

Here's the SMART status:

[image]

And the rest of the info panel:

[image]

I don't know why SpeedFan refuses to show one my of external HDD's but other than that seems to be a decent software. On the scan it seems that all attributes are OK but it's Fitness meter is missing a bar compared to my other external HDD's. The online scan shows everything is fine as well, so sad that WD doesn't support short/extended tests but my other HDD's do support that.

Link to online scan: http://www.hddstatus.com/hdrepshowreport.php?ReportCode=13107053&ReportVerification=AD255581

Comment: Is that representative of the time when you've got your operating system indexing or backing-up the fiiles, what's happening on the software front for it to be active at all?

Comment: @JiminyCricket. It's completely random! For example when I'm not using the device, it starts making noises and sometimes when I'm copying huge amount of files it doesn't make any noise at all!

Comment: Download a monitoring tool like SpeedFan and check the SMART data. It doesn’t sound like a normal kind of noise

Comment: @JamesP `wmic diskdrive get status` returns status OK for all my devices!

Comment: @Shayan: the command you mentioned does not give enough information. A drive can easily show as ‘OK’ / ‘passed’ until it is too late

Comment: @JamesP you are correct. I added the info to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMART looks okay.

It's very hard to diagnose a drive by sound alone. That is to say, with real damage and actual accompanying symptoms it's often obvious, like these examples demonstrate: [northwind.gr/en/data-recovery/damaged-hard-drive-sounds](https://www.northwind.gr/en/data-recovery/damaged-hard-drive-sounds).

My first gut instinct does not say, your drive sounds very alarming. If it's still in it's warranty, take it to the place where you purchased it if you'd feel better with a replacement drive.

You can try ask here: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskADataRecoveryPro/ to get a more authoritative opinion.

Comment: I guess I have damaged heads, sound 18 sounds very familiar to mine! I don't know how I can convince the warranty company that the drive is damaged though, the device plugs in fine, is identified, and works fine, and the clicking noises randomly occur during night usually, there's no way I can convince them the drive is faulty. I just have to pray it fails before the warranty runs out I guess...

Comment: I'm not hearing it, I mean your drive sounding like example 18 (for the WD I assume).